# creating multiple labels with csv

Tags: csv, neo4j

I am trying to load a csv file to create nodes and labels. Is there a way to I add more than one label at the same time? (I am using neo4j 2.1.1)

this is my csv:

```
1,Test1,hardkey,button
2,Test2,touch,button
3,Test3,,screen
```

I tried this:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:/Users/Claudia/Documents/nodes.csv' AS csvLine
FOREACH (n IN (CASE WHEN csvLine[2]='hardkey' THEN [1] ELSE[] END) |
    MERGE (p:hardkey {name: csvLine[1]})
)
FOREACH (n IN (CASE WHEN csvLine[2]='touch' THEN [1] ELSE[] END) |
    MERGE (p:touch {name: csvLine[1]})
)
```

This works, but how do I get the other column ("button" and "screen") included?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

See the [MERGE](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-merge.html#_use_on_create_and_on_match) documentation.

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:/Users/Claudia/Documents/nodes.csv' AS csvLine
FOREACH (n IN (CASE WHEN csvLine[2]='hardkey' THEN [1] ELSE[] END) |
    MERGE (p:hardkey {name: csvLine[1]}) ON CREATE SET p.what = csvLine[3]
)
FOREACH (n IN (CASE WHEN csvLine[2]='touch' THEN [1] ELSE[] END) |
    MERGE (p:touch {name: csvLine[1]}) ON CREATE SET p.what = csvLine[3]
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't load any data into the database. I don't get a error or anything. But in general, "p.what = csvLine[3]" would add a property, isn't it? What if it is a label?

Comment: Edit: it did work, I just fortgot the FIELDTERMINATOR in my example. But there is still the thing with addin a another label.